# intellij javascript support does not work in php files

Tags: php, intellij-idea, ide

I use intellij-idea with php support installed but there is not auto-completion for JavaScript in .php files while  it works fine in .html and .js files 
how to make the the IDE support auto-complete in .php files

Comment: thanks for commenting, after contacting their support team jetbrains told me that this issue has been marked as a bug that affects 2017.2 update and they are working on it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug, a fix for [WI-36767](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36767) will be included in next PhpStorm update

Answer (score -1):

For IntelliJ IDEA, You can easily support auto complete option. You just have to check this option in your compiler settings.

`Build project automatically`

It is basically located under Compiler Settings. See the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: thanks for commenting, after contacting their support team jetbrains told me that this issue has been marked as a bug that affects 2017.2 update and they are working on it.